# Can't connect to some WIFI networks

Tags: wifi

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi to a wifi network using a D-link DWA-125 wifi dongle. I have managed to connect it to a WPA1 network at home and the WPA2 network that an iPhone creates, but I am not able to connect it to the wifi network at my school.

So far I have tried two methods:

1) Using only the /etc/network/interfaces file, and inserting this at the bottom:

```
auto wlan0
wpa-driver wext
wpa-ssid MY_ESSID
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-proto RSN
wpa-pairwise CCMP
wpa-group CCMP
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk MY_HEX_KEY
```

2) Using the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file inserting this at the bottom:

```
network={
ssid="MY_SSID"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="MY_PASSWORD"
}
```

and then inserting this at the bottom of the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

But none of them works. With the first one I get a series of wlan0 DHCPDISCOVER messages on boot followed by a "no DHCPOFFERS recieved", and with the second one I get something along the lines "ipv6 wlan0: link is not ready". Is there something wrong with my configuration? Thank you

Comment: Is the school network ipv6 only?

Comment: Not that I know of but I will check

Comment: I checked, it is not

Comment: Is the school network wpa? Maybe is wep or even not secured at all? Perhaps it uses mac address filtering, vpn, some other form of login required (less likely).

Comment: Also, are you sure that is a wifi connectivity problem? Because is it reaches the point where it looks for dhcp responses, it seems to me that it got connected but could not aquire an IP address. That could indicate a problem with the IP configuration, gateway, etc.